# troubleshoot openvpn connection

Tags: openvpn

I have an account with windscribe vpn.
Using their CLI app works fine.

Have setup the same connection through network-manager (for convenience) using keys, certs, credentials etc supplied from their openVPN Config setup page https://windscribe.com/getconfig/openvpn.

All seems well, get successful connection message but no actual internet access, and vpn disconnects after 60 seconds or so.

Windscribe support say the problem is with failed API calls from elementary's network-manager.

So my question is where do I start to troubleshoot this issue? /var/log/openvpn folder is empty. I have no internal firewall running, and no router, as only mobile data (tethered wifi). If it all works through CLI, then I would think it should also work through network-manager, or am I missing something?

Cheers for any suggestions.

Comment: sorry forgot to state running Hera 5.1.2.

Comment: Same problem here. Could you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the issue by just restarting the network-manager after installing.

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```